# Rotating a layer (created using illustrator) in AE does not rotate it as a group

Tags: adobe-after-effects, illustrator-effects

I created a flower in Illustrator and tried to rotate in AE.
Instead of rotating as a whole layer, I see some jumps.
What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I suggest you see this post: http://leodesenhosecia.blogspot.com/2013/06/adobe-illustrator-efeito-floral.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a wrong step in the Illustrator file rotation:

[image: wrong step]

Comment: But how should that affect the rotation of this entire flower (as a whole) in After effects

Comment: Because the whole object is badly done. When rotating it always there will be a wrong step, independently of the program where you then put it.